# TeamCity and PowerShell dont assigns a value to a variable

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I'm studying team city, and it's just a wonderful thing! However, I have an env.versionReleas to which a value should be assigned in the PowerShell script, but not assigned. The script is quite simple

```
$sss="afaf"
Write-Host "##teamcity[versionReleas name='env.versionReleas' value='$sss']"
```

and this variable remains empty. What am I doing wrong?
TeamCity: 2021.1.1 (build 92714)
Spes settings env did not give anything. It seems that Team city does not respond to my message. The answers that are on the site do not help. The value remains empty, just as it was empty

[image]

Comment: it works as expected in powershell. I think the issue is somewhere else

Comment: @phuclv I don't know what the problem is. It refuses to work, as it is written in the documentation (

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but the name `versionReleas` is missing a final `e`.

Comment: @mklement0 That's a good point, but that's what it's called in my project. I attached a screenshot of how it looks in the project. I hope I did it correctly